# can't map property. Consider to declare/implement a mapping method. Can't generate mapping method from non-iterable type to iterable type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

I can't seem to use mapstruct correctly

```
@Mapping(target = "products", source = "itemBookType")
SearchBookingResult backToTp(ItemBook itemBook);
```

When running this code I get the following error:

```
Can't map property "ProductType itemBookType" to "List<ProductOverview> products". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "List<ProductOverview> map(ProductType value)".
```

I added the following code at the bottom:

```
List<ProductOverview> map(ProductType value);
```

but still it returns me the following error:

```
Can't generate mapping method from non-iterable type to iterable type from java stdlib.
```

Itembook class:

```
public class ItemBook {
    private ProductType itemBookType; //ProductType class
    private Integer idref;
    private String reference;
}
```

ProductType class:

```
public enum ProductType {
    BOOK, PHONE, GAME
}
```

SearchBookingResult class:

```
public class SearchBookingResult extends BaseResponse<SearchBookingResult> {
    private String reference;
    private List<ProductOverview> products;
}
```

the Mapper

```
 @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
    public interface ItemBookMapper {
        ItemBookTpMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ItemBookTpMapper.class);
        @Mapping(target = "reference", source = "idref")
        @Mapping(target = "products", source = "itemBookType")
        SearchBookingResult backToTp(ItemBook itemBook);
        List<ProductOverview> map(ProductType value);
    
    }
```

ProductOverView class is abstract:

```
public abstract class ProductOverview implements Serializable {

    private ProductType productType;

    public ProductOverview(ProductType productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    public ProductType getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }
}
```

map reference work but products return many error.

Comment: You need to implement the method yourself as MapStruct cannot deduce how to convert from your single element to a list element.

Comment: and how? can you give me directions?

Comment: By writing the method? How else would you do it? Instead of only the declaration `List<ProductOverview> map(ProductType value);` write a proper implementation of that method. If you have an interface use a `default` method else use an `abstract` class that implements it (and read the documentation of MapStruct which explains this as well).

Comment: can you give the documentation about it?

Comment: What is it you don't understand about writing a method? That is all you need to do? You have the signature already now write the implementation.

Comment: I said i wrote it but it still returns error

Comment: No you didn't... You wrote the declaration **not** the implementation.

Comment: but the problem is that I don't know how to write the implementation, how, where?

Comment: You know how to write java don't you? Just instead of a method declaration write the actual method as you would write it in any other java class. It is no different then anything else you write.

Answer (score 8):

MapStruct can't generate mapping method from non-iterable type to iterable type because it's impossible to create a generic mapping.

The only solution, as suggested by the exception, is to create a custom method where you can implement your own mapping algorithm.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ItemBookMapper {

    ItemBookMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ItemBookMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "reference", source = "idref")
    @Mapping(target = "products", source = "itemBookType", qualifiedByName = "mapProducts")
    SearchBookingResult backToTp(ItemBook itemBook);

    @Named("mapProducts") 
    default List<ProductOverview> mapProducts(ProductType value){
        List<ProductOverview> products = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //add your custom mapping implementation

        return products;
    }

}
```

- Official documentation: [adding-custom-methods](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods)
- Baeldung tutorial: [mapstruct-custom-mapper](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-custom-mapper)