# How to Use MapStruct mapping from non-iterable to iterable?

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

```
List<MapStructureObjectEntity> toEntityTest(UUID mapId, MapStructureObjectDto.Update update);
List<MapStructureObjectEntity> toEntityTestList(UUID mapId, List<MapStructureObjectDto.Update> updateList);
```

I have a mapper that converts from List to List as above.

I know why it doesn't work. This is because there is a non-repeatable field called UUID, and if you exclude the UUID it works correctly.

I would like to include the UUID mapId with all data being converted.

So far, the list has been individually mapped with mapId in the Stream (or For) method.

```
updateList.stream().map(update -> MapStructureObjectMapper.MAPPER.toEntity(mapId, update)).toList();
```

I don't think this is a clean way because it does the work twice.
(On top of that, the code is decentralized. Oh shit!)

Is there a convenient way to convert this to MapStruct ?

Comment: have you read this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73293525/13115701 ?

Comment: I read that question too, but I couldn't think of a way to use Stream directly inside. Thanks to Gopinath Radhakrishnan, I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default method in the mapper interface that can perform your desired steps. Something like below :

```
public interface Mapper {

  MapStructureObjectEntity toEntity(MapStructureObjectDto.Update update);

  default List<MapStructureObjectEntity> toEntityTestList(UUID mapId, List<MapStructureObjectDto.Update> updateList) {
    return updateList.stream().map(update -> {
      MapStructureObjectEntity entity = toEntity(update);
      entity.setUuid(mapId); // Or additional steps as needed..
      return  entity;
    }).toList();
  }  
}
```

Comment: It's a pity that I had to implement the code myself, but thanks to that, I reduced the code scatter. thank you!